# Python | How to restrict command in the IRC bot?

Tags: python, command, bots, irc, restrict

How to restrict command in the IRC bot written in Python?

For example I have:

```
data. = irc.recv(2048)

if data.find("^cmd",7) != -1:
    irc.send('PRIVMSG ' + channel + ' :' + 'do_something' + '\r\n')
```

But if any user write `bla bla ^cmdblabla` it will works too. I don't want it so how may I restrict it? Tried with `len()` but there is no chance to do it by this way. Seems that regexp also will not help for this.

Comment: Which lib are you using?

Comment: Looks like he wrote his own lib. Bad idea if you have to ask this.

Comment: @LuRsT,`socket`, `string`, `re`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a tuple with the arguments allowed. For example:

```
commands = ("some_command", "other_command", "this_continues")
```

Then just:

```
if not command in commands:
    print("Unrecognized command.")
```

You have to parse the data before to get the command. Maybe like this:

```
command = data[:data.find(" ")]
# And here the code above
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: `if not data in commands:`  
   `irc.send('PRIVMSG ' + ' :' + 'Unrecognized' + '\r\n')`
  
Sadly it doesn't work. Message from server _No text to send_.

Comment: Please provide your full code to see what are you doing wrong.

Comment: Sorry for no linebreaks but have no idea how to do that
`while 1:`  `data = irc.recv(2048)`  `print data`  `commands = ('^cmd', '^cmd1', '^cmd2')`  `if not data in commands:
      irc.send('PRIVMSG ' + ' :' + 'Unrecognized' + 'command' + '\r\n')`

Comment: Sorry, but `data` should be the command, not what you're receiving from server. See the updated answer.

Comment: If statement doesn't wait for any command, it sending message to channel instantly.

Comment: Have you seen my updated answer? What have to do that?

Comment: I tried your code. It must wait for commands from user but it doesn't wait. It is sending text all the time.

Comment: Just add `if not data: continue` after calling `recv`.

Comment: Still the same problem.